# how to change image positions using img tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need change following img tag image position to center how can I do this?

```
<div class="text-center">
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/technet-logo-lg.png" width="300" alt="Technet Logo">
                </div>
```

Comment: text-align: center; to the parent

Comment: can you give code example

Comment: What about you start to learn the basics of CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Give it a `margin:auto;` along with `display:block` and it should be aligned to the center.

```css
img{
  display:block;
  margin:auto;
}
p{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<p>This is some text. <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/200/300" alt="Smiley face" align="middle"> This is some text.</p>
```

Comment: images behave like inline elements, therefore margin auto by itself won't have any effect on image. You can either specify `text-align: cente` on it's parent element or you need to change `display` property of the image to `block` or `inline-block` for margin to have any effect.

Comment: @MarekTakac I was having a brain fart. For some reason I was thinking that it automatically displaying as block.

Answer (score 0):

```
.text-center
{
    text-align:center;
}
```

probably this is  what you want ( [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/5kg0xagz/) )

but if you need to stuck with the inline tag just use :

```
<div class="text-center" style='text-align:center;'>
                    <img  src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/technet-logo-lg.png" width="300" alt="Technet Logo">
                </div>
```

Comment: can't I use this one  <p>This is some text. <img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" align="middle"> This is some text.</p>

Comment: sure you can but you must give the paragraph (text-center) as class value as you gave it to div in the original question